# "HOLA MUNDO "Por que No Compila PHP ? XAMPP/ PHP myadmin / mac os

Tags: xampp

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, escribo un "Hola Mundo" en lenguaje Html/PHP resulta que el archivo lo guardo en la htdoc/Curso/prueba.php . cuando abro el chrome escribo: localhost/Curso/prueba.php

No se puede acceder a este sitiolocalhost rechazó la conexión.
Intenta:

Comprobar la conexión.
Comprobar el proxy y el firewall.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```html
<?php
     
     echo "HOLA MUNDO";


?>
```

Comment: Parece un problema en la config de xampp y no de php per se. En que puerto está xampp escuchando? está encendido? tiene algún error?

Comment: Al abrir localhost en tu navegador, que ocurre ??

Answer (score 2):

Por fin encontre la solucion !! en mi caso es necesario escribir el puerto 8080, es bastante sencillo pero ese simple error me llevo a desisntalar varias veces el xampp , en algunos tutoriales no escriben el puerto y eso se presta a confusion , gracias a todos asi quedaria correctamente :
localhost:8080/Curso/prueba.php